# Definition Query on a Dynamic Mapping Service?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, map-service, definition-query

Will a definition query hinder performance of a dynamic mapping service or will it speed up performance?

Using ArcDesktop 10.3.1 and ArcServer 10.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking. No the speed will not increase. The Definition query will just reduce the amount of background data being showcased online. If you want fast maps the best case from ESRI software currently is to used [Cached maps](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/what-is-map-caching-.htm). In terms of it hindering performance - dynamic services will be slow with dense data and fast with non-dense data. Dynamic services are generated on the fly and serve from client side stored cache (until the client deletes or refreshes their cache)

Take a look at [Performance Considerations for Services](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/communities/enterprise-gis/01n200000011000000.htm) and keep an eye out for [ArcGIS Vector Tiles](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2015/07/20/vector-tiles-preview/) which will speed up the end users experience. Alternatively, you can jump into [Mapnik Vector Tiles](https://github.com/mapbox/mapnik-vector-tile) or [Mapbox Vector Tiles Spec](https://github.com/mapbox/vector-tile-spec) (which are principally the same).

Take a read of the [Performance tips for uncached maps](http://server.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/map-authoring-considerations.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_82FD40791ACE4C05AECB9AA948111CF5)

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a yes and no question,  Yes in that you may see some slight performance gains because you are showing less on the screen, but unless its a massive dataset I wouldnt expect to see a noticable result.

But there are things you can do to speed up performance if that is your goal:

Publishing as an MSD
Create Spatial Indexes 
Use the minimum number of layers that you can get away with
turning on verbose logging and seeing whats hindering the speed

http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=Publishing_optimized_map_services

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/04/27/using-detailed-logging-with-arcgis-server-9-3/